# Python 3 крафт пакетов Ethernet

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7, ethernet, scapy

Пытаюсь подключить микроконтроллер к сети. С компьютера надо отсылать ethernet-пакеты, микроконтроллер будет их принимать. Т.к. SRAM всего 1КБ, то весь пакет принимать нет смысла. Поэтому я хочу отсылать в сеть обрезанный пакет(чтобы весь пакет был около 60 байт). Теперь к делу.
Нашел модуль scapy. Очень долго пытался отослать пакет через IDLE, но ничего не выходило, уже разочаровывался в Pythone...но вот решил сделать тот же код, но в PyCharme и код заработал, в сеть отправлялся нужный мне пакет.
Вопрос, почему в IDLE не отправляется, а в PyCharm код работает как задумано.Хочу разобраться с питоном, чтобы понимать что не так происходит.Смотрел библиотеки,указанные в коде ошибки, но не понимаю, что не нравится Python`у.

```
    from scapy.all import*

    MACD = "01:11:11:11:11:11"
    MACS = "02:22:22:22:22:22"
    IPD = "192.168.0.13"
    IPS = "192.168.0.20"

    pack = Ether(dst = MACD,src = MACS)/IP(dst = IPD, src = IPS)/TCP()/"TEST"

    sendp(pack)
    #это в PyCharm][1]][1]
```

Этот же код в IDLE вызывает ошибку ниже:

```
============== RESTART: C:\Users\Клепочка\Desktop\SendRAWether.py ==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Клепочка\Desktop\SendRAWether.py", line 10, in <module>
    sendp(pack)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.3-py3.7.egg\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 338, in sendp
    realtime=realtime, return_packets=return_packets)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\scapy-2.4.3-py3.7.egg\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 296, in __gen_send
    os.write(1, b".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

[image]

Comment: Есть подозрения, что PyCharm и IDLE используют разные питоны, потому что на Python 3.7.4 этот код выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: Ещё пишут, что ранние версии `scapy` (до 2.3.3) вызывают это исключение в IDLE. Вроде как, пофиксили в 2.3.3.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать ваши рекомендации.

Comment: Установил Pytho 3.7.4 и проверил версию Scapy, она 2.4.3 и всё равно такая же ошибка...Пробовал всё тоже самое в убунту, там тоже пакет не отправляет, но пишет что то другое(к сожалению не помню что конкретно, но другая ошибка 100%). Есть предположение-может быть это в операционной системе дело. У меня windows 7.

Comment: Пробовали запускать скрипт напрямую из терминала?

Comment: Поверить не могу! Попробовал как вы сказали-через командную строку и всё работает без танцев с бубнами, т.е. оригинальная версия библиотеки sendrcv от scapy. Спасибо большое за ответ! Не знаете почему так:через терминал работает, а через IDLE ошибка?

Comment: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/407.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь! Установил pyreadline, но всё равно не работает из IDLE. Буду запускать через консоль.

Comment: IDLE как-то переопределяет `stdout`, поэтому всё работает не так как нужно. Можете сами сравнить `sys.stdout` в консоли и в IDLE, это разные объекты, почему-то.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось таки запустить код из IDLE, подредактировав библиотеку sendrcv.py. Подумал если идл ругается на строки в библиотеки, то уберу их. И вот без этих строк всё работает, пакет отсылается. Теперь интересно понять, что это я выкинул из библиотеки? =)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже на вывод `.` в `stdout`.

Comment: Спасибо!Надо углубляться в питон)